# Select Row in DataGridView with onClick and Accept button c#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I am looking for this solution on internet but I only found to add a button in a column of the *datagridview*.

I have a form like this:

[image]

**What I want to do is when a row is selected (OnClick) and then "button3" is pulsed, do something but I don't know how to do it**.

With doubleClick, I am doing what I want but I want to do it with the button too, so how can I do this?

**EDIT**!! This is my code what is working with doubleClick:

```
private void EmpresasDataGridView_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string nempresa = EmpresasDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CODEMP"].Value.ToString();
        string empresaSeleccionada = EmpresasDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DENOMI"].Value.ToString();

        // Almacenarlo en la key "Empresa" de app.config -> appSettings
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["EMPRESA"].Value = nempresa; //Add("EMPRESA", nempresa);
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        //Cojo el valor una vez cambiado en app.config para asegurar el funcionamiento
        string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMPRESA"];

       // MessageBox.Show("La empresa seleccionada es: " + empresaSeleccionada + " y el código de empresa modificado es: " + configvalue1);
        base.Close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you know how to register the Click event of a Button?

Comment: @MongZhu with onClick?

Comment: You can read gridView's Focused row on Button Click event similar(not exact) to row doubleClick.

Comment: @LuckWallace do you mind posting your current code? It would help a lot. Right now I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: [this Click event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netframework-4.8), in the designer you can simply double click the button and visual studio will register the event automatically. Or did you try it already? because you wrote: "With doubleClick, I am doing what I want but I want to do it with the button too"

Comment: @NeedHelpASAP I have updated the post with the code that I want to use when a row is clicked, and I pulse button3 after!

Comment: @MongZhu If I click over some item of DataGridView two times works fine. But if I want to do it with the button3 I have to get the onclick over some item, and that is what I don't know how to do it.

Comment: double click the button in the designer, then in the eventhandler, get the selected row of the datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to on click button's event. Then just check if any row is selected.

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (EmpresasDataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
            {
                //Do something with row
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, it's easy. You have to set the

```
DataGridView1.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect
```

...which you already have, aparently. Then you simply refere to the selected row as folows:

```
DataGridViewRow drSelected = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0);
```

So you take first item from the collection of the selected rows (you can work with more than one row, if you allow `Multiselect`). You can then put a code in your `Button1` Click event (double-click the button in the designer) to use the row, such as:

```
MsgBox("Selected value of DENOMI column is " + drSelected.cells("DENOMI").value);
```